# why my custom tabs not add in ms word add in?

Tags: javascript, xml, ms-word, office365, office-js

Can't be able to create custom Tabs in Word Add-in , which is used the office.js .

The below manifest.xml file which hot help me for the new custom tab ,

in the code i mentioned the custom tab and where it need to positioned and
the custom as the name of the custom tab

```
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="OfficeTab" id="CustomTabId">
            <OfficeTab idMso="TabHome" insertAfterMso="TabHome"> <!-- Change the Tab Id -->
              <Label resid="CustomTab.Label"/> <!-- Define the Label for your custom tab -->
              <Group id="CustomGroup"> <!-- Define a new Group -->
                <Label resid="CustomGroup.Label"/> <!-- Define the Group Label -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="CustomButton">
                  <Label resid="CustomButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="CustomButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="CustomButton.Description"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
```

but the final results is nothing showed in the tabs bar ,
I tried many times but the result is same .
(Tried the official documentation too...)
[Add Custom element tab link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/customtab?view=common-js-preview)

For the clarification :
"@types/office-js": "^1.0.256"

if anyone have any suggestion on this please help me

The solution which is collaboration between xml and js

Comment: I don't know this area, but the documentation at/near https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/extensionpoint?view=common-js suggests you need <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrmaryCommandSurface"> (and no id attribute). If you are *adding* to the existing HomeTab, in which case you need <<OfficeTab id="TabHome" > (and no insertAfterMso attribute). If you want a new Custom Tab then you need  a CustomTab> element instead of your <OfficeTab> element. Worth checking otherattribute and element names and values using *that* documentation rather than other Ribbon-related documentation.

Comment: You're welcome man! However, despite trying all the mentioned solutions, none of them resolved the issue. So, my company decided to abandon this task. Thanks anyway for your support!

Comment: Fair enough! Doubtless too late now, but it looks like I had a typo and put "PrmaryCommandSurface" instead of "PrimaryCommandSurface".